# При повороте эмулятора, layout vertical не переключается на layout - horizontal

Tags: android, android-layout, экран

При повороте эмулятора, layout vertical не переключается на layout - horizontal.

все сделал по инструкции (https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/14-urok-5-layout-kak-ispolzovat-smena-orientatsii-ekrana.html), а в результате и в вертикальном и в горизонтальном положении эмулятора показывается только layout vertical.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как исправить эту ситуацию?

не помогает даже CTRL+F12

................................................................

манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.p0041basicviews">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

................................................

layout vertical

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Вертикальная ориентация экрана">
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button1">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button2">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button3">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button4">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

......................................................

layout horizontal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Горизонтальная ориентация экрана">
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button1">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button2">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button3">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Button4">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...............................................

MainActivity code

```
package com.example.p0041basicviews;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myscreen);
    }
}
```

Comment: На реальном устройстве не пробовали - может это проблемы эмулятора? Посмотрите в его настройках - активен ли режим авто-поворота, может он заблокирован на портрет (в шторке должно быть). Или покажите свой манифест, разметку и скрин или схему раскрытых папок `layout`.

Comment: @woesss обновил вопрос, добавил инфо о манифесте, text version layouts

Comment: Пока всё верно - если не напутали с именем и квалификатором для горизонтальной разметки, то дело в эмуляторе.

Comment: я новичок в этом дело, все коды layouts были скопированы из одного онлайн урока в том виде какими они есть. Я пробовал запустить двумя разными эмуляторами - результат одинаков. (вопрос обновил, там показаны эмуляторы)

Comment: Чужие приложения переворачиваются в эмуляторе? (напр. Chrome, Youtube, Google Play)

Comment: Может, в коде приложение есть фиксирование ориентации? Это может быть не в манифесте, а в активити, например. Приложите код `MainActivity`, пожалуйста

Comment: @nikialeksey вопрос обновил, можете смотреть код MainActivity

Comment: @RubenKubalyan хм, тогда расскажите как соотносятся `layout vertical` и `layout horizontal` и `myscreen`?

Comment: @nikialeksey на этот вопрос не соображаю нужного для вас ответа. Во всяком случае повторюсь, что я только делаю первые шаги в Android Studio. И отсебятины практически не сделал, даже если делал то, не отдходя из рамок того, чего было описано в первых 5 уроках (ссылку на урок, в рамках которого возник вопрос - я написал в вопросе)

Comment: Если вы всё сделали в точности по уроку, то проверьте настройки эмулятора - откройте шторку, быстрое меню (где кнопочки `wi-fi`, `bluetooth` и т.д.) и убедитесь что активен автоповорот. И как уже сказали выше проверьте поворачиваются ли другие приложения.

Comment: Сделайте еще скриншот структуры проекта с расположением xml-разметки. Там может что не так. Как здесь: https://startandroid.ru/images/stories/lessons/L0005/xL0005_400.png.pagespeed.ic.IVZ4ZffVoQ.webp

Comment: @woesss Благодарочки :) именно в шторке и была проблема, да и собственно понял что означает "шторка" и где она находится. Проблема решена.